# static and non static member data initialization and constructor order

Tags: java, static

I am beginner in Java and stuck with simple concept of initialization of data and constructor calls when there is static member available in definition of class.

Code:

```
class Bowl {
    Bowl(int marker) {
        System.out.println("Bowl(" + marker + ")");
    }
    void f1(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f1(" + marker + ")");
    }
}
class Table {
    static Bowl bowl1 = new Bowl(1);
    Table() {
        System.out.println("Table()");
        bowl2.f1(1);
    }
    void f2(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f2(" + marker + ")");
    }
    static Bowl bowl2 = new Bowl(2);
}
class Cupboard {
    Bowl bowl3 = new Bowl(3);
    static Bowl bowl4 = new Bowl(4);
    Cupboard() {
        System.out.println("Cupboard()");
        bowl4.f1(2);
    }
    void f3(int marker) {
        System.out.println("f3(" + marker + ")");
    }
    static Bowl bowl5 = new Bowl(5);
}
class StaticInitialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating new Cupboard() in main");
        new Cupboard();
        System.out.println("Creating new Cupboard() in main");
        new Cupboard();
        table.f2(1);
        cupboard.f3(1);
    }
    static Table table = new Table();
    static Cupboard cupboard = new Cupboard();
}
```

Output:

```
Bowl(1)
Bowl(2)
Table()
f1(1)
Bowl(4)
Bowl(5)
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
Creating new Cupboard() in main
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
Creating new Cupboard() in main
Bowl(3)
Cupboard()
f1(2)
f2(1)
f3(1)
```

I am unable to understand the flow of code and there is not much explanation in the book where this code appeared except that static members get initialized when they have not been initialized before and when it is necessary.
Any leads?

Comment: All explanation you will find in Java Language Specification document.

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your program starts,

1) **StaticInitialization** class is loaded into memory and its static fields are initialized first in the order they are described

2) Static field *table* is initialized, that's why **Table** class is loaded into memory and all of its static fields are initialized.

3) Static field *bowl1* is initialized, that's why **Bowl** class is loaded into memory but it has no static fields, so the constructor is called and prints *Bowl(1)*

4) Static field *bowl2* is initialized, but **Bowl** class is already loaded, so its constructor is simply called and prints *Bowl(2)*

5) **Table** constructor is called, prints *Table()* and calls method *f1(1)*

6) Static field *cupboard* in **StaticInitialization** class is initalized, that's why **Cupboard** class is loaded into memory and all of its static fields are initialized.

7) Static field *bowl4* is initialized, but **Bowl** class is already loaded, so **Bowl** constructor is called and prints *Bowl(4)*

8) Same with *bowl5* static field.

9) Then, after all static fields of Cupboard are initialized, class members are initialized, that is *bowl3* field. So, **Bowl** constructor is called and prints *Bowl(3)*

10) **Cupboard** constructor is called, prints *Cupboard()* and calls *f1(2)* method

11) Main method starts to work. Prints *Creating...* and creates new **Cupboard** object, so class members of **Cupboard** are initialized. That is, *bowl3* field is initialized within this new object and its constructor is called, so *Bowl(3)* is printed.

12) Constructor of this new **Cupboard** object is called, it prints *Cupboard()* and calls *f1(2)* method of *bowl3* object

13) Steps 11 and 12 are repeated. (Main prints *Creating...* and creates new **Cupboard** object)

14) *f2(1)* and *f3(1)* methods are called one by one on different objects

> Just remember that static fields are initialized once when the class
>   loads into memory and class members are initialized by default when
>   the object is created.